# LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to get next invocation. No Response from endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am getting following exception on lambda function and it is random too

Below is the traceback error

```
RuntimeError: Failed to get next
  File "bootstrap.py", line 480, in <module>
    main()
  File "bootstrap.py", line 462, in main
    event_request = lambda_runtime_client.wait_next_invocation()
  File "lambda_runtime_client.py", line 49, in wait_next_invocation
    response_body, headers = rapid_client.next()
```

Not sure is this aws lambda issue or not as 20% of the times i get this error

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ git libxml2 libxml2-devel libxml2-python libxslt libxslt-devel mesa-libGL mesa-libGL-devel wget nss nss-util zip unzip \
 pango atk at-spi2-atk gtk3 libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXtst cups-libs libXScrnSaver libXrandr GConf2 alsa-lib

ARG PIP_INDEX_URL

COPY requirements/base.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY requirements/test.txt ./test_req.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY service.py ./
COPY local-chromium /var/task/local-chromium
RUN python3.8 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
RUN python3.8 -m spacy download es_core_news_sm


ENV PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
CMD ["service.handler"]
```